# Python regex pattern to match text inside xml string

Tags: python, regex, xml

I'm parsing an XML file and need to remove some clutter from the final output.

```
str = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><chat-message>2018-10
```

my attempt at a solution is:

```
re.sub(r'<(\w|\d|\s){1,}>{1,4}',"",str)
```

and my desired output is:

> 2018-10

Currently Python is finding no matches and just returning `str`. I don't think `<` or `>` are special characters so no escaping needed; I tried escaping anyway and it still did not work.

Comment: Could you give some more examples it's hard to infer what you want to match exactly. For now maybe like re.sub(r'.*>(?!<)', "", str) (We match as much as possible until we hit a > which isn't immediately followed by a <)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something simpler:

```
re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', str)
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner Fred! The look ahead functionality of regex is very confusing to me. I've read some stuff on-line but cannot wrap my head around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion you are better off using an XML parser rather than regex. Here is an example using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlstring = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><chat-message>2018-10</chat-message>'
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstring)

print(root.text)
# OUTPUT
# 2018-10
```

Comment: Did this already. Remnants of the xml tags remain in the parser output.

Comment: @MSanders If the xml is valid, then you could post an example of the xml that is giving you trouble and we may be able to help.

Comment: The xml has a lot of sensitive info in it (SSN, account numbers, etc). The time it would take to redact/remove this info would be insane.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for the test case in your question -

```
r"<[\w\D]+>([-\d]+)"
```

You can test it here -

https://regex101.com/